# connect to exchangeServices to get my calendar and get an error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, exchangewebservices

i try to connect to C# exchange ews via asp.net with my outlook account on the exchange server and i keep getting "When making a request as an account that does not have a mailbox, you must specify the mailbox primary SMTP address for any distinguished folder Ids." when i try to get calendar

connecting to ews:

```
private ExchangeService ConnectToService(ExchangeRetrivalParams exchangeRetrivalParams)
{
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(exchangeRetrivalParams.ExchangeVer);
    service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(exchangeRetrivalParams.Username, exchangeRetrivalParams.Password);
    service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    service.AutodiscoverUrl(exchangeRetrivalParams.Email, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
    return service;
}
```

trying to get calendar:

```
try {
    ExchangeService service = ConnectToService(email, username, password);

    int NUM_APPTS = NumberOfItems;

    // Initialize the calendar folder object with only the folder ID.
    CalendarFolder calendar = CalendarFolder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new PropertySet());
    //get the start and end times
    DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2017, 7, 21);
    DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2017, 7, 23);

    // Set the start and end time and number of appointments to retrieve.
    CalendarView cView = new CalendarView(startDate, endDate, NUM_APPTS);
    // Limit the properties returned to the appointment's subject, start time, and end time.
    cView.PropertySet = new PropertySet(AppointmentSchema.Start,
                                        AppointmentSchema.End,
                                        AppointmentSchema.IsRecurring,
                                        AppointmentSchema.AppointmentType);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    lastOperationErrorMsg = e.Message;
    return null;
}
```

it fails with:

> When making a request as an account that does not have a mailbox, you must specify the mailbox primary SMTP address for any distinguished folder Ids.

on:
`CalendarFolder calendar = CalendarFolder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new PropertySet());`

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so i found it working with:

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService("ExchangeVersion");
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("Username", "Password", "Domain");
service.AutodiscoverUrl("Email", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
```

and now it does connect and retrieve all appointments (according to start and end date) requested.

hope that it's good practice and open for new suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Your using both webcredentials and UseDefaultCredentials eg

```
 service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(exchangeRetrivalParams.Username, exchangeRetrivalParams.Password);
service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

You should be either use one or the other, if your trying to impersonate the currently logged on user then you have to deal with the Kerbros delegation eg I suggest you follow the example in https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/emeamsgdev/2012/11/05/ews-from-a-web-application-using-windows-authentication-and-impersonation/

Comment: if i remove one of these: service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(exchangeRetrivalParams.Username, exchangeRetrivalParams.Password);
service.UseDefaultCredentials = true; then i get an error: "The Autodiscover service couldn't be located."